# Facebook Graph API - Finding friends who like a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'd like to create a call to the Facebook Graph API to find friends who like a specific page.

In FQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=MYPAGEID AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

But this doesn't work as FQL is deprecated.

I can't seem to find a way to do this on the new version of the API.

Any suggestions? Iterating all fans of a page and compare them with the array of is not the best idea I guess? :-)

Thanks,
Koen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook have locked down a lot of options for privacy, but the closest remaining endpoint might be [Social Context](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.4)

So, a call to `graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{page_id}/?fields=context` should show have a `friends_who_like` node, which would show you what you're looking for.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer as correct? Thanks so much :D